# How to initialize members in nested class? C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with initializing members of class inside class.
Let's say that I want to set diameter, width and volume to 1 just like I set x to 1

```
struct car {
    int x;
    struct wheels {
        int diameter;
        int width;
    };
    struct engine {
        int volume;
    };
    car();
    car(wheels w, engine e);
};

car::car() : x(1), wheels::diameter(1), wheels::width(1) {}
```

I also tried do it like this but with no luck:

```
car::car() : x(1), wheels{ 1,1 } {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wheels` and `engine` are just types, there are no data members of those types in your `car` struct, the only data member is `x`.

I think you probably meant to do something like this instead:

```
struct car {
    struct wheels {
        int diameter;
        int width;
    };
    struct engine {
        int volume;
    };
    int x;
    wheels w;
    engine e;
    car();
    car(wheels w, engine e);
};

car::car() : x(1), w{1, 1}, e{1} {}

car::car(wheels w, engine e) : x(1), w(w), e(e) {}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/w8SQt0)

Answer (score 2):

Your class declares the nested classes `wheels` and `engine`, but it doesn't actually contain member variables of type `wheels` or type `engine`. It's pretty easy to fix this:

```
struct car {
    struct Wheels {
        int diameter;
        int width;
    };
    struct Engine {
        int volume;
    };

    int x;
    Wheels wheels;
    Engine engine;
    car() : x(1), wheels{1,1}, engine{} {}
    car(Wheels w, Engine e) : x(1), wheels(w), engine(e) {}
};
```